# On using SelectField from Material-ui MenuItem are not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the 0.20.1 version of material-ui and when I used the Menuitem in the SelectField, It showing the items and  when I click on the items it gives me an error

*React does not recognize the `primaryText` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `primarytext` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.*

**Here is my code of Search Component -**

```
import React from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    amount: 15,
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <SelectField
         name="amount"
         floatingLabelText="Amount"
         value={this.state.amount}
       >
       <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="5" />
       <MenuItem value={10} primaryText="10" />
       <MenuItem value={15} primaryText="15" />
       <MenuItem value={30} primaryText="30" />
       <MenuItem value={50} primaryText="50" />
       </SelectField>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Search;
```

How do i fix this issue ??

Comment: Are you sure it should have a `primaryText` prop, and not just `<MenuItem value={5}> 5 </MenuItem>`?

Comment: Excluded the primeryText prop, it worked.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MenuItem` component put all extra props on the DOM node, and `primaryText` is not a recognized attribute.

You could just remove the `primaryText` prop altogether.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    amount: 15,
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SelectField
          name="amount"
          floatingLabelText="Amount"
          value={this.state.amount}
        >
          <MenuItem value={5} />
          <MenuItem value={10} />
          <MenuItem value={15} />
          <MenuItem value={30} />
          <MenuItem value={50} />
        </SelectField>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```